How to hide base class method from derived class when called inside base class?
In c#, I have a base class:
public class A
{
    private void foo(){}
}

and a derived class B from A.
I want foo() to be hidden from B, so this works fine, I cannot call:
new B().foo()

but I can do this inside A:
public class A
{
    private void foo(){}

    public void bar(){
        new B().foo();  //this compiles, I don't want it to be possible
    }
}

As long as you call a private base  method for a derived class inside that base class, it works. I want the private method to be always hidden.

So if A can't call your private foo, then who can?

@canton7 I think the OP doesn't want to allow A to call foo() on a B instance (only on itself or another A). I don't see how it is possible though in a straightforward way.

Right. So should A be able to call this.foo()? What if this is actually an instance of B: you can't detect whether that is the case at compile-time

There's quite a smell here. Perhaps you can solve this by having a protected constructor that accepts an Action. Then A has another constructor that passes foo as that constructor argument and derived classes have to pass... something else. It's not clear though whether that's a good solution or just making a bad smell worse.

The inheritance is useful if B is A. Maybe in your case it's not a case and you need composition?

Maybe you can create foo as a local function? (I.e., a method inside another method). Looks like a XY problem to me.

Not looking at your reasons, it can be the way to prevent calling a private base class method for the object of the derived class inside the base class:
using System;
public class A {
    private void foo() { Console.WriteLine("A!"); }
    public void boo() {
        new B().foo();
    }
}
public class B : A {
    public void foo() { }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        new A().boo();
        Console.WriteLine("Main.");
    }
}


Main.

So, you can hide the target method by overwriting it in the derived class.

This approach has interesting effect (processed by FW4.8 command-line compiler). Depending on access level combination, it compiles in different ways:
using System;
public class A {
    private void foo() {
        Console.WriteLine("A.foo!");
    }
    private void poo() {
        Console.WriteLine("A.poo!");
    }
    public void boo() {
        var b = new B();
        b.foo(); // calls B.foo()
        b.poo(); // calls A.poo()
    }
}
public class B : A {
    public void foo() { }
    protected void poo() { }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        new A().boo();
        Console.WriteLine("Main.");
    }
}


A.poo!
Main.

And 'B.base.foo()' could be accessed in 'A' anyway by ((A)new B()).foo().
Of cause, the problem statement is initially wrong.

You could make the method virtual in A and override it in B:
public class A
{
    protected virtual void foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A!");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected override void foo()
    {
        // Intentionally doing nothing here.
    }
}

You could in principle also throw an exception in B; however, this would violate the Liskov substitution principle (LSP).

In such way, while 'foo' is better protected against calling from A using ((A)new B()).foo() it becomes available everywhere in B: base.foo().
